# Decode encoded URL with htaccess

Tags: .htaccess, url, redirect, decode, encode

Ok, I've set up a return URL so after a paypal transaction it redirects to this URL:

```
https://legendarymarket.org/index.php?route=checkout/success
```

but paypal is returning it as:

```
https://legendarymarket.org/index.php?route=checkout%252fsuccess
```

I think I cannot do anything about that except redirecting it via htaccess, any help please?

Comment: Why is the `/` double escaped?

Comment: Yea I have no idea why paypal returns "%252f"